# How to pipe CLI return information to run same command

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe

I'm working completely in theory here so please excuse any misunderstandings.  I need to run the same command on each line of a bash command return, but only using a portion of that command's return. Note that this is custom command line return. Example:

```
// initial command
> ~$ device findAll
// returned data
Scanning ...
Network Name   Hardware Address     IPV4 Address    Details
test1          CD:F8:D4:15:3B:AE    172.1.3.22     "Blah Blah Blah"
test1          AB:C1:D2:11:31:EF    192.15.31.2    "Blah Blah Blah"
...
test1          CE:A8:B4:16:3A:FD    172.1.6.21     "Blah Blah Blah"
test1          AC:B1:E2:16:21:DF    172.1.6.22     "Blah Blah Blah"
Total: 600 Devices
```

With this returned data I need to access only the IPV4 address section of each line so that I can ssh into the device and run an update.  I know how to ssh into each device individually, but with 600 returned values, that would be a waste of time. I also do not know how to ignore the header lines and the total line of the returned data.

My question is this:  How can I access only the IPV6 section of the returned data using a only command line?

End result would theoretically be something like:

```
> ~$ device findall | while read -r line ; do
    //access device by ssh command
    scp /current-firmware-pathway/firmware.bin user@**[IPV4 Value Here]**:/tmp/fwupdate.bin
done
```

If storing the return in a variable and iterating over the variable is more efficient, I'm also open to that result.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you use `awk` from the command output? Which `shell` are you in? Can you paste the complete output of `device findAll`, including the headers present?

Comment: I was previously unaware of the awk command at all.  After looking into it, and taking my shell into account,  I can use it.  Janos' answer below works great, which I imagine is where you were going. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy using awk:

```
device findall | awk '$3 ~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}$/ { print $3 }' | while read ip; do
    scp /current-firmware-pathway/firmware.bin user@$ip:/tmp/fwupdate.bin
done
```

With `$3 ~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}$/` we filter the lines,
matching 4 non-empty numeric sequences separated by a dot.
This is not strictly the pattern of IPv4 addresses,
but probably close enough.
If there is a match, we print the 3rd column.
The header and summary lines are ignored,
as they don't match the IP address pattern in the 3rd column.

Comment: I was previously unaware of the awk command at all.  After looking into it, and taking my shell into account,  I can use it. Thank you very much for this quick response Janos!